# How to create css only auto/manual slider

Tags: html, css

Is it possible add manual control to an auto slider in css only or does this require JS or Jquery? The intent is to have an auto slider on a delay and when user selects slider ctrl button from gallery or clicks prev/next button it updates slider to  the next/prev or specifically selected slide displaying it with a longer delay then continues to autoplay next slide if user does not click or select another button.
manual example: https://jsfiddle.net/bnr5k8ah/
auto example: https://jsfiddle.net/mx738n2g/

```
    .fling-minislide {
width:350px; 
height:300px; 
overflow:hidden; 
position:relative; }

.fling-minislide img{ 
position:absolute; 
animation:fling-minislide 20s infinite; 
opacity:0; width: 100%; height: auto;}

@keyframes fling-minislide {10%{opacity:1;} 25%{opacity:0;}} 
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:5s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:10s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:15s;}
```

Comment: You can create a manually-advancing slider without using scripts by using hidden `<input type="radio" />` tricks with the `:checked` psuedo-class, but not automatically.

Comment: @Dai I linked a js fiddle of an auto slider using only css, do you mean I can't combine the both auto and manual functions in one slider without js or jquery?